# Using Kendo Grid in PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, partial-views, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two `<section>` in the Index view of my MVC application and I want to render two partial views in these sections. There is no problem rendering a Kendo grid to one Index. However, in order to render data on Kendo Grid, could I use the two methods returning Json in the controller as shown below.  Could you give me an example how to achieve this?

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Issues_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    IQueryable<Issue> issues = db.Issues;
    DataSourceResult result = issues.ToDataSourceResult(request, c => new IssueViewModel 
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        ProjectID = c.ProjectID
    });

    return Json(result);
}
```

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IssueViewModel>()
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.ProjectID);
      columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
  })
  .ColumnMenu()
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
  .Pageable()
  .Navigatable()    
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
      .Read(read => read.Action("Issues_Read", "Issue"))
      .Create(create => create.Action("Issues_Create", "Issue" ))
      .Update(update => update.Action("Issues_Update", "Issue"))
      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Issues_Destroy", "Issue"))
  )
)
```

Comment: You question is not clear, it's very difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I used <section> in my comment and that cause some text are missed. I updated the question. Could you have a look at please?

Comment: You should clearly state what you intend as it is not clear. Do you want render two partial views with two grids in it? Maybe it's a problem of duplicate id's

Comment: Yes, I exactly want to create 2 partial views and I want to populate one kendo grid each of them. Later, I want to render both of them into one view. Could you help please?

Comment: If I understood correctly, it works fine when you render one partial view. It breaks when you try to render two. If this is the case, it seems that you have a duplicate id problem. Do the grids have different id's?

Comment: Actually I cannot define for one partialview as well. I know it is very easy, but as Kendo Grid uses two method for rendering and reading data, I am very confused. That's why I ask for a sample definition by using Kendo Grid. Thanks for your help..

Comment: What's in your `result` variable, inside the `Issues_Read` method?

Comment: Just one line data having ID and ProjectID fields (just for testing).

Comment: You could add `List<IssueViewModel> list = new List<IssueViewModel>();` and `list.Add()` each of the result lines (use a foreach loop, for example). And finally `return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request));`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But I think there is another problem regarding to the definition of partialview. So, if you would not mind, post your sample code as answer including View, partialviews and controller. Especially control definition is very important. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "problem regarding to the definition of partialview"?

Comment: I have not managed to define partial view definitions unfortunately :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean with partial view definitions. Also, I cannot write all the code for you, controller, view and partials, can I? If you can't display a partial, that's a question you must solve first and then solve this one

Comment: Partial 1: @Html.Partial("grid", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", "grid1" }}) | Partial 2: @Html.Partial("grid", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", "grid2" }}) |  Partial Content: @(Html.Kendo().Grid<IssueViewModel>()
  .Name(@ViewData["id"].ToString())..

Comment: @Tarek Najem Many thanks for your help. But why do not post your answer by showing also the **Controller** and **View** and **Partial Views** samples as an answer? That would be helpful either for me and other people.

Comment: if my answer was helpfull please mark it as answer. Controller code is not included because it's not related to the workaround

Comment: Of course I will. That's why I posted the last comment above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the same partial view multiple times, grid ID should be unique so passing the ID in partial view data is one possible solution. In your case
Partial view first call:

```
@Html.Partial("grid", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", "grid1" }})
```

Partial view second call:

```
@Html.Partial("grid", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", "grid2" }})
```

Partial view content:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IssueViewModel>()
  .Name(@ViewData["id"].ToString())
...
```

Comment: Do you mean with **"... use the same partial view multiple times"** _"multiple times on the same view at the same time"_? Or _"on different views at the same time"_? Could you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: on the same view of course because if on different views ID problem will not exist

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. In that case Whenever I use the same partialview, I have to change the grid id i.e. grid1, grid2, grid3 (for three times usage in this example). Is that true?

Comment: @Christof that's true